# JOOQ RDS Aurora MySQL Support

Tags: jooq

I am a little confused by the JOOQ product compatibility with AWS RDS Aurora MySQL.

Perhaps this purely a licence restriction rather than technical one.

This page https://www.jooq.org/legal/licensing#databases shows RDS Aurora support in Professional Edition & Enterprise Edition. The "License Terms" section on https://www.jooq.org/download/ show that the open source version does not allow for commercial databases and only allows for open source ones.

My question is:

Can anyone confirm that this is actually a licence usage terms restriction, rather than a technical one with the open source code, e.g. it's not that when using the professional edition one actually would run a different flavour of JOOQ, e.g. a different binary with more features?

---

Purely for bonus points & general interest:

We can see in this commit https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/commit/863ade3b3c7a004d477d54193ac5104435b9835b and in this github issue https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5196 dating back to 2018 support was added to the open source project.

Given AWS generally refer to the Aurora product as being *compatible* with mysql 5.7, why would JOOQ need to do anything at all to "support" this, shouldn't it "just" look like using MySQL 5.7 from the perspective of a client application? https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/faqs/ Perhaps the critical word below is "most".

> most of the code, applications, drivers and tools you already use today with your MySQL databases can be used with Aurora with little or no change. The Amazon Aurora database engine is designed to be wire-compatible with MySQL 5.6 and 5.7 using the InnoDB storage engine.

Answer (score 4):

Lukas from the jOOQ team here.

> The "License Terms" section on https://www.jooq.org/download/ show that the open source version does not allow for commercial databases and only allows for open source ones.

Perhaps that section title "License Terms" is misleading for this particular purpose (which we'll review). There's no way for the jOOQ Open Source Edition to *not allow* you to use the jOOQ Open Source Edition with any database product of your choice. The [ASL 2.0](https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0), which is the license governing the jOOQ Open Source Edition, does not allow for any such "amendments" or restrictions on top of the ASL 2.0 - otherwise it would no longer be the ASL 2.0 license.

What this website section means is that the jOOQ Open Source Edition does not technically support any other databases than the ones listed there, nor do we offer any support for such an integration as a vendor, but if you can get it to work (through patching, integration testing, etc.) you're free to do so.

> Can anyone confirm that this is actually a licence usage terms restriction, rather than a technical one with the open source code, e.g. it's not that when using the professional edition one actually would run a different flavour of JOOQ, e.g. a different binary with more features?

There is no "license usage term restriction" whatsoever in the jOOQ Open Source Edition, apart from the [ASL 2.0](https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0)

> Given AWS generally refer to the Aurora product as being compatible with mysql 5.7, why would JOOQ need to do anything at all to "support" this, shouldn't it "just" look like using MySQL 5.7 from the perspective of a client application?

We as a vendor will give you warranties and commercial support, as well as maintenance on your Aurora MySQL integration when you use jOOQ's Aurora MySQL support.

In case you do run into one of those cases where Aurora MySQL doesn't work exactly like vanilla MySQL, we'll fix (or may already have fixed) the issue for Aurora MySQL only, not affecting other MySQL users.